# matplotlib widgets Slider demo source code explanation

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget

I'm trying to understand the [source code](https://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/slider_demo.html) to be able to use the Slider widgets of matplotlib. The piece of code defining function `update()` really bothers me:

I don't see the point of having the argument `val` in `def update(val):`, and the value of `val` is not referred to anywhere. It's the same issue with the `def reset(event):` function. Some simple tests I've done so far:

1. change the name of `val` argument to other random word, say, `def update(wtf):` without changing the body of the function. The resulting code still works as desired.
2. Adding some default value to the argument, say, `def update(wtf=None):` without changing the body of the function. The resulting code still works as desired.
3. Simply remove the argument. `def update():`. The Slider NO LONGER changes the plot, meaning the script is not working.

I don't understand how this `update` function or the `val` argument works. Can someone explain?

Comment: I've never used matplotlib widget before, but just reading from the code, my guess will be the `on_changed()` takes a function and calls it with a parameter, if you don't provide a parameter for `update()` function then it fails silently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `on_changed` callback will supply the current value of the slider to the function. The `update` function therefore needs an argument. The reason this argument is not used in the example is that the `update` function needs the values of both sliders, independently of which one is changed, and therefore takes the values directly from the Slider instances.

To better understand the way the slider works, one may consider the following simplified version:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
s = np.sin(6*np.pi*t)
l, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2, color='red')
plt.axis([0, 1, -1.2, 1.2])

axfreq = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor="lightblue")
sfreq = Slider(axfreq, 'Freq', 0.1, 20.0, valinit=3)

def update(val):
    l.set_ydata(np.sin(2*np.pi*val*t))
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

sfreq.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Here you only have one slider and the value is passed to the update function, where it is used to calculate new ydata values.

Very simlarly, the `on_click` callback of the button passes a click event to the function. This is pretty useless in this case, but could potentially be used to see, which mouse button has been used, or where exactly the click has happened.

```
def reset(event):
    if event.button == 1:
        sfreq.reset()
        samp.reset()
    else:
        print("Please use the left mouse button")
button.on_clicked(reset)
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Ding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44469241/matplotlib-widgets-slider-demo-source-code-explanation#comment75934886_44469241) is right. Going to the implementation [link](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/widgets.py#L425)) (with logical sequence of line 435 | 411->425 ), the function `update` is called with the current value of the Slider on updated. The passed value, however, is not directly used. Instead the current value of the Slider is directly referred to in the user-defined `update` function by a global variable reference.